# Is it possible to receive http requests using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, http

The title says it all.

Is it possible to *receive* http requests using vanilla JS?

I know the `fetch` API allow me to send them, but, as far as I know, there's no way to receive them. If there is, how? Jquery?

Comment: This is not a question of JS, but of where you're running your code. If you're running in a browser, no, because the network stack is not exposed to the browser runtime.

Comment: I don't have code yet. I was asked "build a REST API using Js, but no frameworks"

Comment: You can do that. But you have to execute the code in Node.js, for example, not in a browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS itself has no mechanisms for input and output. It depends on the host environment to provide those.

When people say "Vanilla JS" they usually mean "Core JS + Web APIs as are made available in a `<script>` element in an  HTML document" (where the host environment provided by a web browser).

These APIs provide **no** mechanism for listening for incoming network connections of any kind. You cannot run a web server inside a web browser.

If you want to do that then you'll need an environment which can create network services, such as Node.js.

---

It is possible that [your real problem](https://xyproblem.info/) can be solved some other way. You can listen for server pushed data using [Web Sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). In this case the JS running in the browser needs to connect to a Web Socket server provided by something else (often Node.js) and then that server can push messages to the browser. Most browser based instant messengering services use this technology.

Comment: That's a pretty satisfying answer. Thank you Quentin

Answer (score -1):

The only way in this scenario is to setup a "data pull" strategy to simulate this communication style.

A problem though is that this means the server would be handling many more requests...

```
var fetching = false;

function pollForNewData() {
  if (fetching) {
    // Don't try fetching if we have an existing fetch operation already running.
    return;
  }
  
  fetching = true;

  fetch("https://myserver.net/api/some-source")
    .then(result => {
      // Do something with data retrieved.
      fetching = false; // We're done with this fetch cycle.
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Something went wrong with this fetch cycle.
      fetching = false; // We're done with this fetch cycle.
    });
}

setInterval(1000, pollForNewData); // Poll every second for new data.
```